# How to give Cancel button the same properties as the Close X

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I have a problem whereby I need to give a custom made 'Cancel' button the same properties as the Close X button in the top right hand corner.

My problem is that when I enter some text into a textbox and then click off the text box then my application checks to see if the value entered is valid. This is fine until I click on the 'Cancel' button i.e. to return to the previous screen, it fires the validation still so the user can never get out of the window (unless they press the 'X' button).

Now my question is whether there is a way to give my custom cancel button the same properties as the 'X' button, so my application does not validate the input when the cancel button is pressed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: It seems that you may have setup a click listener in a weird spot, could you provide some of the code for your UI, it would be easier to see exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an InputVerifier to validate your text fields. The you can use the following to prevent validation when you click on the "Cancel" button.

```
JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
cancel.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget( false );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
if(event.getSource()==cancelButton)
{
setVisible(false);                    //for current window
previousWindow=new PreviousWindow();
previousWindow.setVisible(true);
}
}
```